# setAutoresizingMask doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsview, autoresizingmask

I am trying to code a programm from this tutorial:

- Part 1:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScB9ZJbkCJI
- Part2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SHVCtzr3y4

**After setting below code snippet in my code, nothing changes.**

```
 [[_ourViewController view] setAutoresizingMask:NSViewHeightSizable| NSViewWidthSizable];
```

When I run the application, views are still in the upper left corner.

Why doesn´t this work ?

Best regards,
Robby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution ! You have to use `constraints` in der Interface Builder !